# How to convert an one dimensional array to two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multilingual

I have the following array, coming from a form, with multilingual data like this:

```
Array
(
    [en_name] => ...........
    [en_description] => ...........
    [gr_name] => ...........
    [gr_description] => ...........
)
```

How can this array be converted into a two dimensional like:

```
Array
(
    [en] => Array
        (
            [name] => ...........
            [description] => ...........
        )

    [gr] => Array
        (
            [name] => ...........
            [description] => ...........
        )
)
```

Comment: Do the indexes always follow the naming convention shown above?

Comment: Yep, the indices are always a two letter language code and the second level indices like:name, desc, price etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$finalArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
   $tok = explode('_', $key);
   $finalArr[$tok[0]][$tok[1]] = $val;
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: That works just fine. Thank you very much for the rapid answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$output = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
            $prefix = str_replace("_","",substr($val,0,3));
            $ending = substr($val,3,strlen($val));
            if(!is_array($output[$prefix]))
                 $output[$prefix] = array();
            array_push($output[$prefix],$ending);    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array3d = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $keyArr = explode("_", $key);
    $array3d[$keyArr[0]][$keyArr[1]] = $value;
}
```

That should work provided that each key only has 1 underscore.

Comment: This works exactly right, like the above answer. Sorry I can't remember who replied first! Thank you! P.S.: Subscribed to your rss too.

Comment: @anubhava got their about 1 minute before!